# How to grant consistency of number formatting with pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to format a series of tables, containing texts and numbers,  using pgfplotstalble, for a technical document targeting a european audience, therefore I need the comma as decimal delimiter in the output. I have been unable to get the same formatting in the first row of the table, in spite of varoous attempts. (the decimas separator is not the desired comma)
Perhaps a clue: when commenting the line "\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%selecting default font (clone of helvetica)" the first row remains in sans serif font, indicating a "special" behavior for this first row. Any suggestion (as well as any tips to improve the general appearance of the table)  appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}
\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%selecting default font (clone of helvetica)

 \begin{document}
 \begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
AWG 4, 6.1, 9, 3.9, 4.3
AWG 1/0, 6.2, 9, 5.2, 5.7
AWG 2/0, 6, 9, 6.0, 6.6
AWG 3/0, 5.1 ,7.5, 7.0 ,7.7
AWG 4/0, 4, 6 ,7.6, 8.4
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
use comma,
every col no 0/.style={string type, column type={l}},
every col no 1/.style={fixed, column type={l}},
every col no 2/.style={fixed, column type={l|}},
every col no 3/.style={fixed, column type={l}},
every col no 4/.style={fixed, column type={l}},
every head row/.style={
before row={\toprule%
{Wire size}
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Maximum voltage drop (\si{mV})}\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{US military spec.}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{European spec.}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{initial}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{final}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{initial}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{final}\\\midrule}
},
every even row/.style={%
before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{\datatable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the first line of the data file is treated as a header by the `\pgfplotstableread` command if there is at least one non-number entry (such as your "AWG 4").
Add `header=false` to its options, resulting in this line:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{data.csv}{\datatable}
```

However, this creates an new default header numbering the columns, which has to be suppressed in the output. This can be done in the `every head row` style with the option `output empty row`, resulting in this line:

```
every head row/.style={output empty row,
```

See pages 6 and 19 of the [pgfplotstable manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf).
Together as MWE excerpt:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
use comma,
every col no 0/.style={string type, column type={l}},
every col no 1/.style={fixed, column type={l}},
every col no 2/.style={fixed, column type={l|}},
every col no 3/.style={fixed, column type={l}},
every col no 4/.style={fixed, column type={l}},
every head row/.style={output empty row,
before row={\toprule%
{Wire size}
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Maximum voltage drop (\si{mV})}\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{US military spec.}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{European spec.}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{initial}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{final}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{initial}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{final}\\\midrule}
},
every even row/.style={%
before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{\datatable}
```